# What is the refractive index for dilute media?

Tags: electromagnetism, refraction

For dilute media, which I assume is a weakly absorbing medium, I have seen the refractive index $n$ given as

$$n=\sqrt{\epsilon_r}+\frac{\text{Re}\{\tilde{\chi}_e\}}{2\sqrt{\epsilon_r}},$$

where $\epsilon_r$ is the relative permittivity of the medium and $\tilde{\chi}_e$ its complex electric susceptibility. How does this relation follow? Any reference where it is derived?

Comment: Where have you seen this?

Comment: In lecture slides based on Jackson’s book Classical Electromagnetism in conjunction with the Kramers-Kronig relations, but also here https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/dilute-absorbing-medium-nonabsorptive-medium-refractive-index-n0-serves-host-dilute-suspen-q8392779.

Comment: This is not a single-species system. This is a dilute solution of something in a "host" or "matrix" or "background".  The first term if the index of the host and is not dilute.  The second term is the index of the solute which takes into account the polarizability of the host.  That is, the field that a solute particle feels is the sum of the applied field and the field due to the polarization of the host.

Comment: Thanks for the insight @garyp. I guess in $n=\sqrt{1+\chi_e}$ one assumes a vacuum in the background and in $n=\sqrt{\epsilon_r+\chi_e}$ one doesn't.